# Trying to place a number's digits into an array, but it's reversed

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to store the digits of a 4-digit number into an array, but it ends up being reversed: `1234` is stored as `[4,3,2,1]` in the array.

```
int[] nums = new int[4];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    nums[i] = input % 10;
    input /= 10;
    System.out.print(nums[i]);

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more code, expected and the result you are getting now? Inputs?

Comment: lets see your input values that you use?

Comment: You may want to start with reading this to let us help you more efficiently: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Doesn't matter what his input values are. The code will always reverse the input the way it's written. Need to loop backwards, that is one solution.

Comment: If your input value is 1234, the code is working as expected.

Comment: @ambs How so? `input % 10` will first put `4` into `nums[0]`

Comment: @cricket_007 is that not happening? I just assumed he/she forgot to separate "4321", it's hard to tell with poorly formatted questions.

Comment: @ambs Clearer now?

Comment: length of what? And what's value of input?

Answer (score 2):

`input % 10;` will return the tens position of the number first, so just loop backwards over the array positions.

```
for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

You could also use an ArrayList and check `while(input > 0)` to do any length number.

Comment: No worries @cricket_007, I mess up the loop invariants most of the times too.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to traverse the array in a reverse order, since number % 10 will give you the digit in the ten's position.

eg: if number 1234 , number % 10 => 4 which should be stored at the end of your array viz nums[3]

```
for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    nums[i] = input % 10;
    input /= 10;
    System.out.print(nums[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change array index:

```
nums[nums.length - i - 1] = input % 10;
```